# Cleaning my php contact form from captcha

Tags: javascript, php, html, contacts

I have some trouble cleaning and making my contact form working.

I'm using a template which had a captcha validation and I don't want it. There was also a "website input that I delete.

I'm a newbie in php so I don't really know what I have to remove and I don't want to start a new php/js files

My contact-send.php file is in a php folder. So I assume the action call in the html is good.

I have two other files in there ( captcha_page.php and image.php but I won't use here, will delete it, so I don't post code )

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="php/contact-send.php">

<p class="input-block">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" />
 </p>

 <p class="input-block">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *" />
 </p>

 <p class="input-block">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>   
 </p>


 <p class="input-block">
    <button class="button turquoise submit" type="submit" id="submit"><i class="icon-paper-plane"></i></button>
 </p>

 </form><!--/ .contact-form-->


<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {

    if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "contact_form_request") {

        $ourMail = "xxx.xxxx@gmail.com";

        $required_fields = array("name", "email", "message");
        $pre_messagebody_info = "";

        $errors = array();
        $data = array();

        parse_str($_REQUEST['values'], $data);

        //check for required and assemble message

        if (!empty($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $name = strtolower(trim($key));
                if (in_array($name, $required_fields)) {
                    if (empty($value)) {

                        if ($name == "name") {
                            $errors[$name] = "Please enter your Name before sending the message";
                        }

                        if ($name == "message") {
                            $errors[$name] = "Please enter your message ";
                        }

                        if ($name == "email") {
                            if (!isValidEmail($value)) {
                                $errors[$name] = "Please enter correct Email address";
                            }           
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        session_start();
        $verify = $_SESSION['verify'];
        if ($verify != md5($data['verify'])) {
            $errors["verify"] = "Please enter correctly captcha";
        }

        $result = array (
            "is_errors" => 0,
            "info" => ""
        );

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            $result['is_errors'] = 1;
            $result['info'] = $errors;
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit;
        }

        $pre_messagebody_info .= "<strong>Name</strong>" . ": " . $data['name'] . "<br />";
        $pre_messagebody_info .= "<strong>E-mail</strong>" . ": " . $data['email'] . "<br />";
        $pre_messagebody_info .= "<strong>Website</strong>" . ": " . $data['website'] . "<br />";

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers.= "From: " . $data['email'] . "\r\n";

        $after_message = "\r\n<br />--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n<br /> This mail was sent via contact form";

        if (mail($ourMail, "Email from contact form", $pre_messagebody_info .="<strong>Message</strong>" . ": " . nl2br($data['message']) . $after_message, $headers)) {
            $result["info"] = "success";
        } else {
            $result["info"] = "server_fail";
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
}

function isValidEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

?>


    if ($('.contact-form').length) {

        var $form = $('.contact-form'),
            $loader = '<span>Loader...</span>';
            $form.append('<div class="hide contact-form-responce" />');

        $form.each(function () {

            var $this = $(this), 
                $response = $('.contact-form-responce', $this).append('<p></p>');

            $this.submit(function () {

                $response.find('p').html($loader);

                var data = {
                    action: "contact_form_request",
                    values: $this.serialize()
                };

                //send data to server
                $.post("php/contact-send.php", data, function (response) {

                    $('.wrong-data', $this).removeClass("wrong-data");
                    $response.find('span').remove();    

                    response = $.parseJSON(response);

                    if (response.is_errors) {

                        var p = $response.find('p');

                        p.removeClass().addClass("error");
                        $.each(response.info, function (input_name, input_label) {
                            $("[name=" + input_name + "]", $this).addClass("wrong-data");
                            p.append(input_label + '</br>');
                        });
                        $response.show(300);
                    } else {
                        $response.find('p').removeClass().addClass('success');
                        if (response.info === 'success') {
                            $response.find('p').append('Your email has been sent!');
                            $this.find('input, textarea, select').val('').attr('checked', false);
                            $response.show(300).delay(2500).hide(400);
                        }

                        if (response.info === 'server_fail') {
                            $response.find('p').append('Server failed. Send later!');
                            $response.show(300);
                        }
                    }

                    // Scroll to bottom of the form to show respond message
                    var bottomPosition = $response.offset().top - 50;

                    if ($(document).scrollTop() < bottomPosition) {
                        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : bottomPosition });
                    }


                });

                return false;

            });
        });

    }
```

sorry, html, php and js are together, didn't manage to make something better...

thanks a lot guys !!!

remi

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Note, you're also publishing your email in plain text in a public forum. If your goal is to not receive spam, you should probably edit your question and remove that. Hopefully the bots can't see past revisions.

Comment: start from indenting your code properly so it won't break my eyes.

Comment: why don't you just start with a simpler tutorial to begin with?

Comment: @Mike I would like to delete the php which arent usefull anymore because I don't need the captcha

Comment: @mike thanks, but not a problem, it's a mail only for this kind of stuff

Comment: @loic sorry, I said "sorry, html, php and js are together, didn't manage to make something better..." can't edit better, this ctrl K are killing me

Comment: @andrew I'm working on a new one right now from a tutorial. I posted here because I believed it was better to use a cleaner version of the code from the template than making a new one which gonna fail anyway if I don't understand how element work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these lines :

```
   $verify = $_SESSION['verify'];
    if ($verify != md5($data['verify'])) {
        $errors["verify"] = "Please enter correctly captcha";
    }
```

Comment: Now, I just have to made something saying "mail has been sent" because we didn't see it and I'm afraid people would send billion mail lol

Comment: An easy way to do this, is set `$_SESSION['mail'] = true;` when you actually send the mail, and then test if this session var is true before sending another one. (plus the echo for the client to know it has been sent). Note that this is isn't safe, but remains pretty easy to implement.